# Does a text change to an aspx file in an ASP.NET WebForms site cause restart

Tags: asp.net, webforms

As the title really.  I was wondering if changing just the text in a Webforms *.aspx file will cause the site to recompile and therefore drop any existing sessions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing a single`aspx` should not cause a restart of the site, just a recompilation of the page resource.

I have made such changes in live sites in the past without any problems.

Comment: Thanks Oded.  As I suspected but just wanted to be absolutely sure.

Answer (score 4):

Its really funny that i was doing some research on appdomain recycles this morning. Basically if you change any of the following then the appdomain will recycle:

- machine.config
- web.config
- global.asax
- /bin folder

or if, The number of re-compilations (aspx, ascx or asax) exceeds the limit specified by the  setting in machine.config or web.config  (by default this is set to 15)

now asp.net doesnt know if the change to a page is a text change or a code change so will therefore need to recompile that page

you can change this default threshold in your web.config but setting the following tag

```
<compilation debug="true" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="x">
```

where x is the new number you want it to be

hope this works for you as it has jsut worked for a site i work with

thanks

paul